# How to make cart clear when "add to cart" button is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm looking to make it so that every time the "add to cart" button is clicked, it clears out the cart. We already have a plugin that bypasses the cart screen and goes straight to the checkout page, but now we have the issue of people adding the same thing to the cart multiple times, or adding multiple products. We are selling a school registration, so only one needs to (and should) be bought at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will empty your cart whenever item is added to cart, thus allowing only one product to be bought at a time. Hope it works for you.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'allow_only_one_product' );

function allow_only_one_product( $cart_item_data ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation" filter.
It is called when wc is validating the item before adding to cart.
You can empty the cart using this filter.